# File manager detects Android device but gvfs folder is empty. How can I access the MTP device from terminal?

Tags: android, mtp

Directories `/run/user/1000/gvfs` and `~/.gvfs` are emtpy and non-existing, respectively. My graphical file manager (Thunar) is able to detect and access the internal and external memory of the device.

Command `gvfs-mount -l` yields:

```
Volume(0): SAMSUNG Android
 Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorMTP)
 Mount(0): SAMSUNG Android -> mtp://[usb:002,003]/
   Type: GProxyShadowMount (GProxyVolumeMonitorMTP)
```

I assume there must be a mount point somewhere since Thunar is able to access it. Where can I find the mount point of the device from the command line? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Have you tried the `mount` command, same as `cat /proc/mounts`?

Comment: @mikewhatever yeap, I tried that and it seems that MTP devices are not listed under those commands

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You must have fuse support in gvfs.

For example, under debian, it is the `gvfs-fuse` package which provides this.

gvfs mounts can then be accessed in `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/...`

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you give more details?  OP already mentions `gvfs-mount`.  What is to do besides?

Comment: The gvfs packages installed on my Debian:
`gvfs:amd64`,
   `gvfs-backends`,
    `gvfs-common`,
    `gvfs-daemons`, 
    `gvfs-fuse`,
    `gvfs-libs:amd64`.

With Thunar, I can mount my smartphone and browse its files.

Once my smartphone is mounted with Thunar, I can also access the files by `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=smartphone_hostname/`.

But if the `gvfs-fuse` package is not installed, I can still access the files through Thunar.

But I can no longer access `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=smartphone_hostname/` because `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` remains empty.

Comment: Thank you so much @logypock you save my day!